# C++ two objects holding pointers to different parts of the same array

Tags: c++, pointers

I try to create two classes, Volume and Slice, and create a method in Volume so it can return part of its data as a Slice object. I want the two objects to share the memory to change any of them will change the same data. Currently, I have:

```cpp
#include <complex>
using namespace std;


class Slice{
public:
    Slice(unsigned long Nx,unsigned long Ny){   //Contructor
        nx = Nx;
        ny = Ny;
        data = new complex<double>[Nx*Ny];
    }

    Slice(unsigned long Nx,unsigned long Ny,complex<double>* inputDataPtr){ //Contructor
        nx = Nx;
        ny = Ny;
        data = inputDataPtr;
    }

    Slice(const Slice&  inputObj){ // Copy contructor
        nx = inputObj.nx;
        ny = inputObj.ny;
        data = inputObj.data;
    }

    ~Slice(){ //destructor
        delete data;
    }
private:
    // DATA:
    unsigned long     nx;
    unsigned long     ny;
    complex<double>*  data;
};

class Volume{
public:
    Volume(unsigned long Nx,unsigned long Ny,unsigned long Nz){ //Contructor
        nx = Nx;
        ny = Ny;
        nz = Nz;
        data = new complex<double>[Nx*Ny*Nz];
    }

    ~Volume(){ //destructor
        delete data;
    }

    const Slice& get_slice(unsigned long zindex){
            return Slice(nx,ny, &(data[zindex*nx*ny]));
    }
private:
    // DATA:
    unsigned long     nx;
    unsigned long     ny;
    unsigned long     nz;
    complex<double>*  data;
};



int main(){
    unsigned long Nx = 1;
    unsigned long Ny = 2;
    unsigned long Nz = 3;

    Volume testVolume(Nx,Ny,Nz);
    /* initialise data in testVolume */
    Slice slice = testVolume.get_slice(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I also need to be able to create individual slices that are not related to the volume, so slice class has to allocate its own pointer as well.

When I run this, it says*** free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000ff1180 ***

I think the problem is when I call the get_slice method of the testVolume, the code will destroy the temporary slice object in the return, so it tries to free a non-existing pointer and cause problems.

How do I avoid this? After a bit of search, I probably need a smart pointer shared_ptr? How do I incorporate it?

Thank you.

Comment: If `Slice` only ever contains part of `Volume`'s data, then `Slice` should not be `delete`ing anything. Also, returning a reference to a local object (as you do in `get_slice`) is bad.

Comment: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the Slice also needs to contain data separately in other cases. As the first constructor shows, it will allocate an array in some cases...

Comment: `shared_ptr` is indeed a solution.

Comment: You can use a flag for "should_delete".  But, Jarod42 probably has the better method.

Comment: ChrissMM is right that you should never delete stuff you didn't allocate, but also even if you were allocating it, you would need to initialize the pointer to something (either an allocation or nullptr) to ensure `delete` doesn't delete at an undefined address

Comment: So should I change the data pointer in both objects to  "shared_ptr<complex<double>>" Do I need to change anything else? Thanks @Jarod42 @ ChrisMM

Comment: @ChrisMM: Answer provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <complex>

class Slice{
public:
    Slice(unsigned long Nx, unsigned long Ny) :
        nx(Nx),
        ny(Ny),
        data(std::make_shared<std::complex<double>[]>(Nx*Ny))
    {}

    Slice(unsigned long Nx, unsigned long Ny, std::shared_ptr<std::complex<double>[]> data) :
        nx(Nx),
        ny(Ny),
        data(data)
    {}

private:
    unsigned long     nx;
    unsigned long     ny;
    std::shared_ptr<std::complex<double>[]> data;
};

class Volume{
public:
    Volume(unsigned long Nx, unsigned long Ny, unsigned long Nz) :
        nx(Nx),
        ny(Ny),
        nz(Nz),
        data(std::make_shared<std::complex<double>[]>(Nx * Ny * Nz))
    {
    }

    Slice get_slice(unsigned long zindex)
    {
        // Use std::shared_ptr aliasing constructor
        return Slice(nx, ny,
                     std::shared_ptr<std::complex<double>[]>(data, &data[zindex * nx * ny]));
    }
private:
    // DATA:
    unsigned long     nx;
    unsigned long     ny;
    unsigned long     nz;
    std::shared_ptr<std::complex<double>[]> data;
};



int main(){
    unsigned long Nx = 1;
    unsigned long Ny = 2;
    unsigned long Nz = 3;

    Volume testVolume(Nx,Ny,Nz);
    /* initialise data in testVolume */
    Slice slice = testVolume.get_slice(1);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/329mqj)

Answer (score 0):

For starters this function

```
const Slice& get_slice(unsigned long zindex){
        return Slice(nx,ny, &(data[zindex*nx*ny]));
}
```

has undefined behavior because it returns a reference to a local object of the type `Slice` that will be deleted after exiting the function.

Secondly this constructor

```
Slice(unsigned long Nx,unsigned long Ny,complex<double>* inputDataPtr){ //Contructor
    nx = Nx;
    ny = Ny;
    data = inputDataPtr;
}
```

does not create dynamically the data pointed to by the data member `data`. So calling the destructor

```
~Slice(){ //destructor
    delete data;
}
```

of an object created such a way again can result in undefined behavior.

A similar problem exists with the copy constructor

```
Slice(const Slice&  inputObj){ // Copy contructor
    nx = inputObj.nx;
    ny = inputObj.ny;
    data = inputObj.data;
}
```

The same memory can be tried to delete two times by the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You problem originates here:

```
   Slice(unsigned long Nx,unsigned long Ny,complex<double>* inputDataPtr){ //Contructor
        nx = Nx;
        ny = Ny;
        // this is a shallow copy
        data = inputDataPtr;
    }
```

Now when you delete it here you are actually deleting the one in Volume

```
 ~Slice(){ //destructor
        delete data;
    }
```

Once the destuctor of Volume is called you try to delete it again:

```
  ~Volume(){ //destructor
        delete data;
    }
```

Which results in the error.
To correct this just don't delete it in the Slice destructor.

You should also change this function:

```
const Slice& get_slice(unsigned long zindex){
            return Slice(nx,ny, &(data[zindex*nx*ny]));
    }
```

Currently you are returning a reference to a local object which will be destroyed the moment you return. To fix this you should consider either using a raw or a shared_ptr.